# Task manager showing absurdly high network throughput in VM

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, linux-kvm

I've got an instance of Windows 10 running in a KVM instance and the task manager in it shows ridiculously high total network throughput (150-900 Gbps upload and download on a 1Gbps link).

Has anyone else noticed this behavior and if so how have you fixed it?
[image: Task manager screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing the board model to PCI, Legacy.
[image: change to 'PCI, Legacy']

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Change network card to virtio and install the driver in windows for virtio. Note, changing network card will cut the internet connection in your VM until you update the network card drivers. Since I am using Rocky Linux 9, I could download these drivers with

```
dnf install virtio-win
```

on the host. Then mount the cd image, that I found in Rocky Linux under /usr/share/virtio-win/virtio-win.iso in your Windows 10 VM and install the drivers. Internet restored and phantom traffic disappeared.